# XPath expression for parsing WiX Processing-Instructions as MsBuild properties

Tags: xpath, msbuild, wix

I have the following wix include **VersionFile.wxi**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include>
  <?define ProductVersionMajor = "1" ?>
  <?define ProductVersionMinor = "00" ?>

  <?define ProductName= "MyProduct" ?>

  <?define UpgradeCode = "myUpgradeCode" ?>
</Include>
```

Now I want to get e.g. the ProductVersionMajor as "1" or ProductName "MyProduct" (without quotes) using XmlPeek and a XPath query. With following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Target Name="Test">

    <XmlPeek XmlInputPath="VersionFile.wxi"
             Query="//processing-instruction('define')[starts-with(., &quot;ProductVersionMajor =&quot;)]">
      <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="Peeked" />
    </XmlPeek>

    <XmlPeek XmlInputPath="VersionFile.wxi"
             Query="//processing-instruction('define')[starts-with(., &quot;ProductVersionMajor=&quot;)]">
      <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="Peeked" />
    </XmlPeek>

    <Message Text="@(Peeked)"/>

  </Target>

</Project>
```

I already got it down to

```
<?define ProductVersionMajor = "1" ?>
```

But goal would be

```
1
```

Any help how to tweak the XPath query highly appreciated. Also it'll be great to have a placeholder **"ProductVersionMajor*="** instead using XmlPeek twice.

---

```
<XmlPeek XmlInputPath="ProductVersion.wxi"
Query="substring-before(substring-after(//processing-instruction(&quot;define&quot;)[starts-with(., &quot;ProductVersionMajor=&quot;)],&quot;),&quot;)">
  <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="Peeked" />
</XmlPeek>
```

unfortunately only produces an

*error MSB3734: XPath Query "substring-before(substring-after(//processing-instruction("define")[starts-with(., "ProductVersionMajor=")],"),")" cannot be loaded. 'substring-before(substring-after(//processing-instruction("define")[starts-with(., "ProductVersionMajor=")],"),")' has an invalid token.*

Assume that XmlPeek needs some more custom XPath syntax possibly?

---

Yes. Tried it as well. Now also tried

```
Query="substring-before(substring-after(//processing-instruction('define')[starts-with(., 'ProductVersionMajor =')],&apos;&quot;&apos;),&apos;&quot;&apos;) ">
```

Also no success. Error is

error MSB4018: The "XmlPeek" task failed unexpectedly.\r
error MSB4018: System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.\r
error MSB4018:    at System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Select(XPathExpression expr)\r
error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.XmlPeek.Execute()\r
error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()\r
error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, Task
LoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult)

Answer (score 1):

Form the xpath point of view the following should do:

```
Query='substring-before(
    substring-after(
         //processing-instruction("define")[starts-with(., "ProductVersionMajor =")]
         ,
         &apos;&quot;&apos;
         )
         ,
    &apos;&quot;&apos;
    )'
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with this approach. Hope it helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <UsingTask TaskName="GetWixDefine"
             TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
             AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">

    <ParameterGroup>
      <File ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" Output="false" />
      <DefineName ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" Output="false" />
      <Value ParameterType="System.String" Output="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>

    <Task>
      <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
      <Using Namespace="System" />
      <Using Namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" />
      <Using Namespace="System.Xml" />

      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
          this.Value = string.Empty;

          XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
          xmlDoc.Load(this.File);
          string selector = string.Format("//processing-instruction('define')[starts-with(., '{0}')]", this.DefineName);
          XmlNode defineNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(selector);
          if (defineNode == null)
            throw new Exception("define not found");

          string regex = string.Format("{0}[ ]*=[ ]*\"(?<value>.*)\"", DefineName);
          Match match = Regex.Match(defineNode.InnerText, regex);
          if (!match.Success)
            throw new Exception("cannot match correctly");

          this.Value = match.Groups["value"].Value;
        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>

  </UsingTask>

  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <GetWixDefine File="VersionFile.wxi" DefineName="ProductVersion">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" ItemName="ProductVersionValue"/>
    </GetWixDefine>
    <Message Importance="High" Text="ProductVersion: @(ProductVersionValue)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```